# Can Jews make a Siyum on mussar literature

Tags: halacha, mussar-ethics, meal-seudah, siyum, orach-chaim

In Halacha, can Jews make a Siyum upon completion of mussar literature? For example to eat  meat during the 9 days.  Or no, is  this  not a type of Torah learning which would warrant a Siyum Seudat mitzvah?

Comment: How could anyone studying Musar ever think they've finished?

Comment: As per @DoubleAA, by definition you can't finish a mussar *sefer*.